# ASP.NET Core for AWS ECS requires VIRTUAL_HOST

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs

I'm deploying an ASP.NET Core Web API app as a docker image to AWS ECS, so use a task definition file for that.

It turns out the app only works if I specify environment variable `VIRTUAL_HOST` with the public DNS of my EC2 instance (as highlighted here: http://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-docker-aws-ecs), see `taskdef.json` below:

`{
    "family": "...",
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "image": "...",
            "name": "...",
            "cpu": 128,
            "memory": 256,
            "essential": true,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 0,
                    "protocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "VIRTUAL_HOST",
                    "value": "ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Once the app is deployed to AWS ECS, I hit the endpoints - eg http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/v1/ping

- with the actual public DNS of my EC2 instance in `VIRTUAL_HOST` all works fine
- without the env variable I'm getting "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" from nginx/1.13.0
- and if I put an empty string to `VIRTUAL_HOST` I'm getting a "502 Bad Gateway" from nginx/1.13.0.

Now, I'd like to avoid specifying virtual host in the taskdef file - is that possible? Is my problem ASP.NET Core related or nginx related?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon ECS have a secret management system using Amazon S3. You have to create a secret in your ECS interface, and then you will be able to reference it in your configuration, as an environment variable.

```
{
    "family": "...",
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "image": "...",
            "name": "...",
            "cpu": 128,
            "memory": 256,
            "essential": true,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 0,
                    "protocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "VIRTUAL_HOST",
                    "value": "SECRET_S3_VIRTUAL_HOST"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> Store secrets on Amazon S3, and use AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles to grant access to those stored secrets in ECS.

[Full blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/security/how-to-manage-secrets-for-amazon-ec2-container-service-based-applications-by-using-amazon-s3-and-docker/)

You could also make your own NGinx Docker image, which will already contain the environment variable.

```
FROM nginx
LABEL maintainer YOUR_EMAIL

ENV "VIRTUAL_HOST" "ec2-xx-xxx-xxxxxx.compute1.amazonaws.com"
```

And you would just have to build it, ship it privately and then use it for your configuration.

Comment: You might also be able to use the Parameter Store in your ECS web interface.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not too concerned with security for now, just want to avoid specifying additional infrastructure details in the taskdef - is that possible to avoid `VIRTUAL_HOST` at all? I updated the question to be more specific

Comment: Well, I can't really help you more than that since this is related to ASP.NET (not to NGinx).

Comment: Hmm no it does seem nginx related - see https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#usage

Comment: Ah yes you are right, I've edited my answer to add a workaround, at the end.